# IIS Compression: Enable GZIP and DEFLATE using Powershell

Tags: iis-6, powershell, compression, gzip, iis

How does one do the following things with IIS 5.1/6.0 using PowerShell:

- Enable HTTP Compression
- Set GZIP and DEFLATE file extensions
- Enable Dynamic and Static compression for GZIP and DEFLATE
- Set the compression lvl

Any pointers to tutorials on this would be appreciated as I have yet to come across any that explain how to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial line of attack with PowerShell is to use WMI. Unfortunately, the root\MicrosoftIisV2 namespace is set up with non-standard security settings which you can't change in PS (not in V1, at least, V2 may be different).

I would suggest looking at the IIS ADSI provider, specifically the IIsCompressionScheme object - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524574.aspx

You may be able to work with this in PowerShell by manipulating

```
$obj = [ADSI]"IIS://MachineName/W3SVC/Filters/Compression/Scheme"
```

However, ADSI is pretty evil, so you'll have a fairly steep learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

Metabase Explorer lets you set these values.  You can automate setting values by linking against IISMbLib.dll, as a [post of mine to StackOverflow explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922472/programatically-removing-etag-suffix-change-number-from-the-metabase-iis6).

You could do something similar with this, or you could use the ADSI namespace as owenevans00 says.